# Write a Select query in POSTGRESQL to replace the null to current datetimestamp, calculate the diff between two column and sum them which has same id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table name Taskstime,

1. I want to add current timestamp where the enddate column has null values
2. I want to get the diff between the startdate and end date
3. Sum all the differences having same task id

Table data:

[image]

What I have achieved till now,

My query:

```
SELECT 
    "StartDate",
    COALESCE("EndDate", Current_timestamp) AS Enddate,
    "Task_id",
    (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ("EndDate" - "StartDate"))) AS hours
FROM
    "Tasks_Taskstime"
```

Output:

[image]

I don't get why the dynamically created end date is not getting calculated.

Desired output: I have created an Excel to show the desired output that I want to have:

[image]

Comment: None of the pictured end dates appears to be null? Is that screenshot from the table, or the output of the query?

Comment: Just a second i have uploaded the output of that query,. let me update the question.
I have updated the question please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enddate is populated, I think your problem is `hour` column which is because when enddate is null you don't replace it with currentdate in you hour column calculation:

```
SELECT
    "StartDate",
    COALESCE("EndDate", Current_timestamp) as Enddate,
    "Task_id",
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (COALESCE("EndDate", Current_timestamp) - "StartDate")) as hours,
    SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (COALESCE("EndDate", Current_timestamp) - "StartDate"))) over (partition by task_id)
From "Tasks_Taskstime
```

if you only want the sum result:

```
SELECT
    Task_id,    
    SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (COALESCE("EndDate", Current_timestamp) - "StartDate")))
From Tasks_Taskstime
group by Task_id
```

Comment: This query does return the output but it does not satisfy third condition where you have to sum all the hours column  which has same taskid

Comment: @Anonnmus see updated answer, but if you have to show us your desired output if this isnot the output you want

Comment: I tried my best to show you the output that i want, if you have any doubts let me rephrase the third statement , I want the sum of the hours having same task_id and group the output by task_id.

Comment: @Anonnmus well, seems like my answer is still relevant. doesn't it produce what you want?

Comment: You answer does sum up all the hours value having same task_id,  but it does not group the table by task_id column which is what i want to achieve

Comment: @Anonnmus if you wanna show startdate/enddate and hour diff of each task alongside sum of diff of same task_ids in the same select, this is the way to go